# close database connection after calling callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Just not sure about the flow of this code

```
doStuff()
  .then(() => { callback(); })
  .catch(err => callback(err))
  .then(db.close);
```

Would db.close get called in this scenario?

Comment: Yes until and unless the catch is called because of an error. The last then would be called.

Comment: @Sumit Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would always be called, assuming that `callback(err)` does not, itself, throw.

This code is nearly equivalent (slightly different error handling) and is a bit more succinct:

```
doStuff()
    .then(callback, callback)
    .then(db.close)
```

Another point worth mentioning is that if `db` is an instance of a class and `close()` is relying upon that via the `this` keyword, then passing it in this manner could be problematic, since it loses that context when called on its own.